# AfxBeginThread() PostMessage to change contorls

Tags: multithreading, user-interface, winapi, mfc, afx

I have a program with AfxBeginThread() that needs to send postmessage to the main dialog in order to change listcontrol data.

How do I achieve that, because I need to pass text I want to change and element change text to? How would I do it?

Comment: The first overload for [AfxBeginThread](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3w9x78e.aspx) has a `pParam` parameter. That's how you pass all information to a thread that it needs, like the window handle for your dialog. Unless you provide a custom implementation that deals with ownership, you cannot use `PostMessage` to transfer freestore data. Use `SendMessage` instead, and clean up resources when it returns.

Comment: I need to pass hwnd of main dlg and pointer to dlg (because i don't know if i can get pointer to dlg from hanlde). Also, what i should pass to sendmessage (except main dlg hanlde and message type) in WPARAM and LPARAM?

Comment: `pParam` is of type `void*`. You can pass **any** structure you wish, and it can be arbitrarily complex. Although chances are, that you do not ever need a pointer to the `CDialog`-derived object, the structure can contain a pointer to this object as well. The parameters to `SendMessage` are message-specific, and documented alongside the respective messages. It's probably a very good idea to learn the Windows API **thoroughly** before moving on to MFC. It is challenging enough, even when you are intimately familiar with the Windows API.

Comment: Okay, thanks. I've passed all my arguments thorugh structure. But still there's a litle question. There's function that i defined at messagemap afx_msg LRESULT UpdateItemData(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam); and it must change some values in listcontrol. But can i add aditional parameters to it? Or how must my thread coummunicate with main dialog?

Comment: You really, **REALLY** need to learn the Windows API first. If you don't, you'll stand not the least tiny bit of a chance to understand code flow in an MFC application. All your message handlers are hidden behind preprocessor macros, making it almost impossible to understand, what's going on. That said, you don't usually call message handlers directly. You'd rather send messages and have the framework call them in response.

Answer (score 0):

Call the API version of SendMessage (::SendMessage(hwnd, w, l) so you don't use a pointer to the dialog. The pointer to the dialog is thread-local.

The LPARAM that you pass in ::SendMessage can be a pointer to anything. If you need to pass more than one parameter then create a struct that contains all the parameters and pass a pointer to that struct. In the message handler function get the individual parameters out of the struct.

Comment: Wait a minute. So, i can use LPARAM to pass any walues i want? What about WPARAM? I mean, what i have to pass with wParam?

Comment: The pointer to the `CDialog`-derived object is just your average pointer. There's nothing thread-local about it. It's valid in every thread in the process. The **pointed-to** data, namely the `HWND` member, however, has thread **affinity**. That's why you don't want to call any member functions from threads other than the owning thread.